# Улучшение формулы

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Вот скажите, у меня, к примеру, есть число 1. Я хочу посчитать, каким будет число, если взять 0.8%, но в программном коде. Как это сделать? У меня есть формула, которая просто вычисляет то, что мне надо, а как туда внедрить ещё и комиссию?

```
label1.Text = "Число: " + (summ * Convert.ToDouble(numAmmount.Value));
```

Comment: Непонял вопроса.

Comment: Что есть комиссия? Что значит "внедрить"? Куда внедрить? Что дано?

Answer (score 1):

```
label1.Text = "Число: " + (summ * Convert.ToDouble(numAmmount.Value) * 0.008);
```